# Eclipse.exe icon vanishes before launching

Tags: eclipse

I have downloaded eclipse.exe.When I click the icon eclipse icon disappears.
the eclipse.ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
 --launcher.defaultAction
openFile
 --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
 256M
 -showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
 -vmargs
 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
 -Xms40m
 -Xmx512m
```

By running the following command on command prompt

```
    eclipse -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\bin\javaw.exe
```

I am getting a error.
java was started but returned exit code=1

Comment: What is the error message? Please include it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot determine what's wrong from the information given, but here are some things to check/try:

If you're running a 64-bit Windows, chances are you have installed a 64bit JDK and try to use it with 32bit Eclipse. If this is the case, you either need to get a 64bit version of Eclipse or install a 32bit JDK and point Eclipse to that (in 64-bit Windows 7, the 32-bit stuff is under "C:\Program Files (x86)").

To get more information what is causing the failure to start, locate the eclipse log -file, it should contain more information about what goes wrong in the start up. I don't remember the precise location, but it could have been something like ***Eclipse root***/configuration/ OR ***workspace root***/.metadata/. You can also start eclipse from command prompt with parameter **-consoleLog**, in which case the error message should be printed straight out to your command prompt.

You could also try starting Eclipse with parameter **-clean**, this flushes some configuration stuff and can sometimes help, if Eclipse seems to crash constantly (but usually you get to the workspace before it does).